# TestComplete Out of memory issue

Tags: automation, testcomplete

The problem we face when we try to run our automation script on for long hours is in between the execution we face with “Out of Memory” issue.This issue is bcoz GDI Object” leak happening due to which the RAM is becoming full and the tool is throwing the error.Is it possible to release these GDI objects through test complete script?

Comment: welcome on stackoverflow. have a look here before posting further questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are having a lot of performance counters on your project and the memory consumption for long executions are weird. Try removing all of them and reexecuting your project. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: We dont have any performance counters,but application is very heavy and we added lot of wait statements in between.Without this wait automation is failing